# Isomorphic ring implies isomorphic modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I thought of the following statement

> Let $A,B$ be unital rings, such that $A \stackrel{f} \cong B$. Then $A$, $B$ are isomorphic as $A$-modules.
>
> $B$ is made an $A$-module by defining $a \cdot b:= f(a) b$. The module properties are satsified as $f$ is a ring homomorphism.

I wonder if my proof is correct:

> $f:_AA \rightarrow _AB$ is a $A$-module homomorphism as it is a bijective group homomoprhism and 
>   $$ f( a \cdot x ) = f(a) f(x) = a \cdot f(x)$$

Comment: What is meant by $f:_AA \rightarrow _AB$?

Comment: I am saying the original map $f:A \rightarrow B$, can be regarded as an $A$-module homomorphism. $_AB$, $_AA$ means that the objects under consideration are left $A$-modules.

Comment: Looks good to me.